# ALTER permission on database allows creation of security principals

Tags: sql-server-2016, permissions, security, role

It appears the `ALTER` permission granted at the database level allows the principal to which it is granted, to create security principals in the database.

Consider the below example:

```
/* setup database */
CREATE DATABASE MyNewDB
GO

USE MyNewDB
GO

/* create a login and user and then grant ALTER permissions */
CREATE LOGIN MyLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'My57r0ngp455w0rd'
CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyLogin
GRANT ALTER TO MyUser
GO

/* running as our new user which only has ALTER permissions, create a user and a role */
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'MyLogin'

CREATE USER UserCreatedByMyLogin FOR LOGIN SomeOtherLogin
CREATE ROLE RoleCreatedByMyLogin
ALTER ROLE RoleCreatedByMyLogin ADD MEMBER UserCreatedByMyLogin

REVERT 

/* verify success */
SELECT  USER_NAME(role_principal_id),
        USER_NAME(member_principal_id)
FROM    sys.database_role_members
WHERE   role_principal_id = USER_ID('RoleCreatedByMyLogin') AND
        member_principal_id = USER_ID('UserCreatedByMyLogin')
```

The user MyUser is able to create a user, a role and then add the user to the role, with only ALTER permissions.

[The documentation for ALTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) states

> ALTER
>
> Confers the ability to change the properties, except ownership, of a
> particular securable. When granted on a scope, ALTER also bestows the
> ability to alter, create, or drop any securable that is contained
> within that scope. For example, ALTER permission on a schema includes
> the ability to create, alter, and drop objects from the schema.

[The documentation for CREATE USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states

> Requires ALTER ANY USER permission on the database.

[The documentation for CREATE ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states

> Requires CREATE ROLE permission on the database or membership in the
> db_securityadmin fixed database role.

so none of the documentation appears to outline the behavior I am seeing above. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ALTER also bestows the ability to alter, create, or drop any securable
> that is contained within that scope.

USER is a database-scoped securable (see the [table in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#_permissions)) so `CREATE USER` permission was conferred by `GRANT ALTER` on the containing database securable.

Comment: thanks. The table clears that up a bit. I've always thought a user / role was a principal rather than a securable - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/principals-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15 so it looks like they are actually both https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/securables?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, it makes sense that a user is both a principal and a securable as they can be assigned permissions - `GRANT SELECT ON Mytable TO MyUser` but also have permissions assigned on them - `GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::MyUser TO SomeOtherUser`